# Relationship between the eigenvalues of a matrix and its Cholesky decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, cholesky-decomposition

Cholesky decomposition states that if $A$ is symmetric positive semidefinite matrix , then there exists a lower triangular matrix $L$ with nonnegtive diagonal elements such that

$$ A = LL^T $$

Is there any relation between the eigenvalues of $A$ and the elements (not the eigenvalues) of $L$?

Comment: The product $LL^\top$ is $A$, so your question becomes "relation between eigenvalues of $A$ and the elements of $A$". Is this what you wanted to ask? Or did you mean "elements of $L$" rather than "elements of the product $LL^\top$"?

Comment: @angryavian Yes you are right

Comment: @angryavian taking $L=UD^{1/2}$ generally will not result in a triangular matrix, which is required in Cholesky factorization.  In the case of $A\succ \mathbf 0$ you can do this and still have $L$ be lower triangular *iff* $U$ is diagonal, i.e. *iff* $A=D$

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any particular relationship between them. You could, however, state some trivial facts, for example:

1. $A \geq 0 \Rightarrow l_{ii}\geq0$
2. $\prod \lambda_i = \prod l_{ii}^2 $

Also, note that you cannot take $L=UD^{1/2}$ ($UDU^T$ being the eigendecomposition of $A$), because there is no guarantee for $L$ to be lower-triangular (which must be the case for Cholesky factorization).

Cholesky decomposition is only a concise representation of Gaussian elimination and my understanding is that, it is too weak to reveal any information concerning the eigenstructure of $A$.